# How to access directory path in Xamarin.Forms for iOS & Android?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms, and want to save some files like CSV, PDF in the device using Export to CSV / PDF.

And to do that I need to access device directory and path. But using Xamarin.Forms, How can I access directory and path in Xamarin.Forms for iOS & Android?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Android specific (Pictures, for example, are in): var javaFile = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
           (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim); // use javaFile.AbsolutePath then javaFile.Dispose()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Environment.GetFolderPath cannot be used with PCL project.(But shared project,It can)
If you plan to use PCL path, You can use 'Dependency Service' Feature.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

use Interface(on PCL) that inject from Concrete Class (From iOS/Android). (Sound Hard,But It's easy)

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with a code snippet doing the job.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

Answer (score 2):

You could use **System.Environment.GetFolderPath** to help with things such as this.

i.e.:-

```
string strFolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

In **Android** this will return something along the lines of */data/data/MyProject/files*

You can then just append your filename onto the end and then start creating and writing to the file etc.

Comment: The above example, as @jojobarcream mentions is applicable only to Shared Projects if you are using that approach and not available in a PCL project.